# How to make the MUI Autocomplete read only?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using [`@mui/material/Autocomplete`](https://mui.com/api/autocomplete/), I cannot for the life of me make the component read only!

Even if the `renderInput` function returns a `<TextField readOnly />` component, the drop down menu still trigger `onChange` events.

I tried `<Autocomplete readOnly />`, but the property gets ignored.

This seems to be a gross design oversight, or am I missing something? Not all components support the same properties.

Currently, I found that using `disabled` instead of `readOnly` yields the desired result, however this creates a non uniform form; certain fields are read only, others are disabled.

---

### ** Edit **

Those finding this issue should upvote and follow the ongoing [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/29344) on Github.

---

### ** Solution **

This is the working solution I have used :

```
import React, { forwardRef, useState } from 'react';
import PropType from 'prop-types';

import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const AutocompleteEx = forwardRef(({
   readOnly,
   renderInput,
   ...props
}, ref) => {
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
   
   return (
      <Autocomplete ref={ ref }
         open={ open }
         onOpen={ () => !readOnly && setOpen(true) }
         onClose={ () => setOpen(false) }
         disableClearable={ readOnly }
         renderInput={ ({ inputProps, ...params }) => renderInput({ ...params, inputProps: { readOnly, ...inputProps } }) }
         { ...props }
      />
   );
});
AutocompleteEx.propTypes = {
   readOnly: PropType.bool,
   renderInput: PropType.func.isRequired
};
AutocompleteEx.defaultProps = {
   readOnly: false
};

export default AutocompleteEx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [v5.4.0 release](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/releases/tag/v5.4.0), MUI added a `readOnly` prop that can be passed directly to the `Autocomplete` component:

```
<Autocomplete readOnly {...yourOtherProps} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control the `open` state and make sure the dropdown is not opened if the `Autocomplete` is read only:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
const [readOnly, setReadOnly] = React.useState(false);

return (
  <>
    <Button onClick={() => setReadOnly((o) => !o)}>toggle readonly</Button>
    <Autocomplete
      options={top100Films}
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => !readOnly && setOpen(true)}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      disableClearable={readOnly}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, readOnly }}
          label="Movie"
        />
      )}
    />
  </>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This solution will do until the @mui theme finally fix (?) this inconsistency.

Comment: @YanickRochon this is probably unplanned when they were designing the `Autocomplete`. There is an ongoing [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/29344), go upvote the post if you think it should be implemented.

Comment: thank you for the link! I will add it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

We can use readOnly property to disable edit option in the autocomplete in the following way

```
import React from 'react'
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'


export default function Select({
    onChangeInput,
    label,
    name,
    value,
    options,
    placeholder,
    disabled,
    error,
    helpertext,
    required,
    shrink
}) {

    const _onChange = (e, v) => {
        onChangeInput(v)
    }

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            freeSolo
            fullWidth={true}
            multiple={false}
            margin={'noraml'}
            readOnly={disabled} // protect edition option by the user
            name={name}
            isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.label === value.label}
            value={value}
            options={options}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            renderInput={params => (
                <TextField {...params}
                    label={label}
                    error={error}
                    required={required}
                    shrink={shrink}
                    helperText={helpertext}
                    variant={'standard'}
                    InputLabelProps={{ style: { fontSize: 18 } }}
                />
            )}
            onInputChange={_onChange}
        />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution could be :- just add *readOnly={Boolean}* as  prop.

attached working sample

```
 <Autocomplete
    autoComplete
    id='combo-box-demo'
    options={allCities}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => {
      return option?.name;
    }}
    openOnFocus
    readOnly={!isEditable}
    includeInputInList
/>
```